# Unable to read websphere custom properties in web.xml

Tags: websphere, web.xml

I am trying to read my config files outside of my war file, So I declare a custom property / variable in Websphere 7.1. But some have websphere was not able to read the variable / token.

Error :

2015-04-30 18:19:57,459 ERROR [server.startup : 0] [] [] [com.abc.config.admin.ConfigTool] - 
com.abc.config.AbcConfigException: Exception in loading configuration from file (${abc.config.dir}/configs): Parameter 'directory' is not a directory

web.xml:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>secondaryBasePathList</param-name>
        <param-value>${abc.config.dir}/configs</param-value>
        <description>
            Directory/Path where the external files required for the
            configuration framework
        </description>
    </context-param>
```

Here are the following ways I tried:
1. Set the property / token at server JVM Custom properties (as per Websphere document :https:// www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/xrun_jvm.html?cp=SSAW57_7.0.0%2F3-16-5-448)

2. Set the property / token as websphere variable (as per Websphere document : https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/ucws_rvars_inst.html )
3. Set the property / token at server web container Custom properties (as per Websphere document :https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.zseries.doc/ae/rweb_custom_props.html )

All the above are not working for me..

Thanks
Dhana

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere Application Server does not support variable substitution in web.xml files.  Your best option would be to declare an `<env-entry>` and specify a binding while installing the application (either an actual value or a lookup-name to a value bound in the default namespace).

Comment: thanks bkail, I will try using <env-entry> attribute and update you.